# Getting the random rows from the DataFrame with step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

As getting the random values can be retrieved by using  `range(start, stop[, step])`

However, I tried this function, `np.arange()` and set `the np.random.seed(10)` and `dataset.sample(n=5)` , but they do not work with my case.

What I am doing is that I import the 5 columns and 100 rows data from the excel file and I would like to randomly select 5 rows from the a column having integer values of 1-100. However, I would like the randomly selected numbers to have the step of 20.

Do you have any recommendation?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi Kathie, can you elaborate your question with a [mre]. Please also add your code along with the sample inputs and expected output. thanks!

Comment: You want the selected sample to have a certain quality (being within 20 steps) which means the values you want to get are not random.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iloc() function for this purpose, you can provide a random index list to fetch records you want.

```
df.iloc[[list_of_random_index_you_want]]
```